# Axis label in MATLAB for high precision values

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I am trying to plot an array of data in MATLAB as follows:

```
ans = [8.1, 8.1+(10^-11) , 8.1+2*(10^-11) , 8.1+3*(10^-11)]
labels = [8.1, 8.1+(10^-11) , 8.1+2*(10^-11) , 8.1+3*(10^-11)]
plot([1,2,3,4],ans)
```

The above code produces this:-

[image: plot]

The problem is that the Y-axis displays the same value/number/label for all data points. How can I set the plot in a way to show these labels more precisely? (for example `8.1`, `8.1+10^-11`, ... or `8.10000000001` )

I tried the command below but it did not help.

```
set( gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca, 'YTick'));
```

Can anyone please help improving this plot to reflect the differences between data points?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your problem with MATLAB 2016a. I ran the first three lines stated by you in the beginning of your question, and got this result:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/fxRak.jpg (although values specified by you as `label` doesn't do anything here). Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. I am using MATLAB 2014b.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue by running this line:  `set( gca, 'YTickLabel', get(gca, 'YTick'));`  Are you always running your code with this line? If yes, try running your code without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually control the format of the Y-axis label in Matlab.
So, the following code will work on the versions higher than Matlab2015b.

```
res = [8.1, 8.1+(10^-11) , 8.1+2*(10^-11) , 8.1+3*(10^-11)];
plot([1,2,3,4],res);
ay=gca;
ay.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%.12f';
```

If you want to manually control the format of the Y-axis tick labels on your version, you should do something similar to

```
res = [8.1, 8.1+(10^-11) , 8.1+2*(10^-11) , 8.1+3*(10^-11)];
plot([1,2,3,4],res);
ay=gca;
currTicks=get(ay,'YTick');
for i=1:size(currTicks,2)
    newTickLabels(i,1)=cellstr(sprintf('%.12f',currTicks(i)));
end
set(ay,'YTickLabel',newTickLabels);
```

I did not test this code on Matlab2014b, but I don't see any functionality that it would be lacking (at least to my knowledge).

In Matlab 2016a, there is no problem right "out of the box" by copying and pasting your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code you gave for controlling the format of the Y-axis tick labels( for Matlab2014b users) works well.